# Modify DevExpress XtraEditor PopupContainerEdit Footer

Tags: devexpress, xtraeditors

[image: PopupContainerEdit]

How can I modify the Footer in a DevExpress PopupContainerEdit.

The screenshot is from the DevExpress online docs: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument612

I am using the PopupContainerEdit and have assigned a PopupContainerControl but I only have a close button at the bottom left corner, but what I want to have a Ok and a Cancel button myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should hide the standard close button (popupContainerEdit.Properties.ShowPopupCloseButton = false) and add all the required buttons to the PopupContainerControl yourself.

Comment: Yepp, that did it. But I also needed to get rid of the bottom strip to avoid a big margin at the bottom of the control. I achived that by setting `PopupContainerEdit.Properties.PopupSizable = false`. Now I can't resize my control but that's ok because I use a FlowLayoutPanel with AutoScroll and it's very rare that the content won't fit the defined size of my control.